# Equivalent of Excel's NETWORKDAYS function with Jet ADO

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, jetsql

Is there a way of replicating Excel's NETWORKDAYS when connecting to a Jet database via ADO?

Comment: this can't be moved with a bounty. sorry. :(

Comment: I suggest asking this on SO with more background explanation -- as in, what the heck does NETWORKDAYS do?

Comment: Cheers, thought the bounty may interfere with things.

Comment: NETWORKDAYS is a function from the Analysis ToolPak add-in.  It returns the number of whole working days between a start date and end date. It excludes weekends and any dates identified in holidays, which you have to pass in as an argument. Function signature is

`NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date,holidays)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First assuming we know both the start and end are weekdays then, I think this works:

```
([DateEnd]-([DateStart]+(Weekday([DateEnd])-Weekday([DateStart]))))/7*5+(Weekday([DateEnd])-Weekday([DateStart]))+1
```

- work out number of weeks between the dates and times by 5.
- add difference of the weekday
- add one to include both start and end

If you dont know that both are work days you need a correction. I think this is correct:

```
([DateEnd]-([DateStart]+(Weekday([DateEnd])-Weekday([DateStart]))))/7*5+(Weekday([DateEnd])-Weekday([DateStart]))+1+IIf(Weekday([DateEnd])=7,-1,0)+IIf(Weekday([DateStart])=1,-1,0)
```

I tested it against Excel, and it appears to give the correct answer

Comment: Excellent, this works well.  I had tried this kind of thing but got bogged down in the logic.  Ta muchly :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also [this function](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetserver.asp.general/browse_thread/thread/dde8757efac1fee/9a323acecf7e4372?lnk=st&q=calculate+weekdays+group%3A*.asp&rnum=3#9a323acecf7e4372).  It is algorithmically nearly identical to @JDunkerley's - just more verbose.  Possibly easier to implement in different environments.

Comment: This would work from with Access where custom functions are exposed, but AFAIK this wouldn't work over an ADO connection.

Comment: Agreed.  i thought the post was useful because it was the same algorithm implemented differently, the sort of thing you could use as a back check, etc.

Comment: Sorry, had to vote down - link takes me to a google site that asks me to log-in.